# Combining Multiple Materials Without Image Texture Nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, baking

I would like to be able to combine a number of materials together into a single texture map.

I have attempted to go through the baking process, however I believe the problem is that none of the materials have a texture outside of their base color as seen below

[image: All the Materials have this setup but with different base colors]

Is there any way to bake all of these materials into a single texture without a texture map assigned to each material? Or, perhaps there is a way for the texture map to inherit the base color from the shader itself?

I would be happy to provide more context for this question if it helps.

Comment: You can try to duplicate the model, remove all the materials one of them and add a new with a texture map. Then bake with "Selected to Active".

Comment: I have tried that but there is an error where it complains that all of the materials don't have an image texture